# MySQL server version Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

So my webserver seems to have been upgraded when I check on cPanel it says the following -

```
Apache version  2.2.26
PHP version 5.4.38
MySQL version   5.5.42-37.1
```

This code was working before so does anyone know what version I need or how I can change it to work now?

**Error -**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND status = 2' at line 1' in advert_search.php:122 Stack trace: #0 advert_search.php(122): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in advert_search.php on line 122
```

**Php -**

```
            //Count The Results
            $count = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ref) FROM adverts WHERE location IN ($qMarks) AND status = 2");
            $count->execute();
            $count = $count->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: The error message indicates looking into `$qMarks`.

Comment: Aha thank you I think I know the issue now, thanks for that I assumed the query